# Crystal Reports in VS 2010 not working on Web Server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports to generate a report and save it as a PDF in a folder. Everything works fine on the local machine. The code is working fine and the report is generated and saved as a PDF as well.

Now, coming to the server, I do not have a VS 2010 installed on the web server. But I had a website application created in ASP.NET framework in VS2010 that I deployed on the server and it is working fine even with no VS2010 on the server.

But now I had to generate the crystal report and save it in the folder. This is another module of the same website. But when I put the .aspx and .aspx.cs and .rpt file on the server, I get an error "Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified".

So, I tried installing the crystal report package from [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A%20CystlR%20%2528SAP%20Weblogs%253A%20Crystal%20Reports%2529) but it says it needs VS 2010 for completing the installation. So, not sure if I can do it without VS 2010 on the server.

Is there any way to do it with no VS 2010 on the server, or I have to install VS 2010 for sure on the server, or any other installation that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Crystal Reports 2010 Redistributable located here (The SAP website is not the friendliest):

[SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

P.S. : SAP website is subject to change, don't mind editing or commenting this answer with up to date info.

Comment: I do not have VS 2010 on the server at all.

Comment: Thanks Mat...that did help...Now I have another problem....where it pops up a box and asks for database log on and requires some further information.....I am not sure what is to be done with it...Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @user613037 : np, you should create another question with more details for your other problem, and accept an answer if it resolved your first issue.

Comment: Preferable to link to this page instead of directly to the zip downloads. It shows the latest updates and service packs. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 As of this date it is at SP5.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Crystal merge modules on the server. You should never need to install visual studio on a server.